# Who's the character in the red jacket at the end of Abobo's Big Adventure?

Tags: game-identification, abobos-big-adventure

During the long final cutscene of [Abobo's Big Adventure](http://www.abobosbigadventure.com/), there's a brief image of some of the audience for Abobo's boxing match with Little Mac:

[image: Audience at the end of Abobo's Big Adventure]

I recognize everyone except for the character at the top center of that image; all that can be seen is a red jacket with a pink stripe.  Who is it?

Answer (score 3):

To me, it looks more like [adult Link](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Link#Adult) from [Ocarina of Time](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time) wearing a [Goron Tunic](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Goron_Tunic) (see the tunic collar and the shoulder belt for holding his sword):

[image: Red Tunic Link]

Comment: Link is already in the picture, and nothing else matches.

Comment: This is a different Link, another character

Comment: Is the white cravat a default part of the outfit? If so, your answer is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The question assumes that the person in the red top and pink sash is meant to resemble a known video game character and is not simply an extra. If that is the case, the only popular characters that I can think of would either be Terry Bogard from *Fatal Fury* or Samurai Jack in a red outfit (not canon). It is entirely possible that the person was intentionally drawn out of the frame because they are not intended to bear specific resemblance to any other character.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not familiar with Abobo's Big Adventure, the image appears to include [Carmen Sandiego](https://carmensandiego.fandom.com/wiki/Carmen_Sandiego), who has enjoyed a slew of namesake video games. She commonly has a scarf, though rather than pink it is often either yellow or orange. As briefly modeled below, Carmen has been through a number of minor costume design changes over the years.

Additionally, as Abobo's Big Adventure celebrates the NES (see [here](http://www.abobosbigadventure.com/about.php)), and at least one Carmen Sandiego title has been released on the platform (see [here](https://nesguide.com/games/where-in-time-is-carmen-san-diego/), ), Carmen seems to be a viable candidate.

[image]